# GUID/RAW stored in oracle match almost, except for last 4 characters

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, guid

We have noticed some strange behavior in our production data concerning the GUIDs we are storing from a .Net DataSet into an Oracle RAW column.

We have the following set up:

- **Table A** has a RAW column **Id**
- **Table B** has an RAW column **ResponsibleObjectId**

The ResponsibleObjectId column is filled with the ID of table A when it is created in function of Table A (not always the case, so there is no FK on the column).

This happens in our .Net server layer. The two tables are in 2 separate DataSets.
These 2 datasets are then saved to an oracle DB (11g).

Most of the times this works, but in a few cases (like 1/10.000.000 rows) the resulting guids are not entirely the same:

```
ResponsibleObjectId                 ID
665B8FFDE5A04163A96D96A25702665B    665B8FFDE5A04163A96D96A257023065
325C8AB000434503B8D2F980B33B325C    325C8AB000434503B8D2F980B33B4B58
AF831B5207E04D2ABE0E3ADAC802AF83    AF831B5207E04D2ABE0E3ADAC8023FA1
88DD5AF244DC4EA08075DB53CA1988DD    88DD5AF244DC4EA08075DB53CA19072E
75A5E5111DEE4021BA6EB016178775A5    75A5E5111DEE4021BA6EB01617876E66
```

They match, expect for the last 4 characters.

We save the GUIDs using a stored procedure as follows:

**.Net DAL**

```
OracleCommand cmdSpInsert = (OracleCommand)database.GetStoredProcCommand("PKG_TableB.InsertTableB");
database.AddInParameter(cmdSpInsert, "PAR_ResponsibleObjectId", DbType.StringFixedLength, 36, "ResponsibleObjectId", DataRowVersion.Current);
```

**Oracle SP**

```
PROCEDURE InsertTableB
(
    ...
    PAR_ResponsibleObjectId IN CHAR,
    ...
)
IS BEGIN
    INSERT INTO StockMov
           (
                ...
                HEXTORAW(REPLACE(UPPER(PAR_ResponsibleObjectId), '-','')),
                ...
           );
END InsertTableB;
```

We have no idea what is causing this strange behavior. We've seen it happen in one similar case on 2 different columns in our Table A as well, so it does not seem related specifically to table B.

If any extra information is needed, please ask and I'll update the question.

Any help is greatly appreciated in solving our mystery! :)

**Edit**
As asked in the comments, the assignment of the ResponsibleObjectId column very simple, like this:

```
dataSetB.ResponsibleObjectId = dataSetA.Id
```

Also the two datasets are saved in the same transaction.

Comment: I don't know oracle much... but can you not use `DbType.Guid` and pass  a `Guid` rather than a `string`? or does Oracle not support guids natively? If this was SQL Server, I'd be using the `uniqueidentifier` native database type...

Comment: We could indeed pass in a byte array, but our dal logic has been this way for several years and it would be quite a big change to implement this. That said, if this would solve our issues, we would certainly have to consider it.
Do you have any idea if/why passing in a string could be causing us these problems now?

Comment: I notice for the bad values the first four digits and the last four digits are the same.

Comment: Wow, good call brian! Did not see that before :)

Comment: Of course, the correct answer is to use the right data type in your code.  That said ... Your question is a bit confusing.  First you say: "The ResponsibleObjectId column is filled with the ID of table A " and next your say: " The two tables are in 2 separate DataSets. These 2 datasets are then saved to an oracle DB (11g).".  Is this two transactions or one?

Comment: You show the insert into Table B (StockMov), but what is the code that gets the ID value from Table A?  
Maybe, you are passing the bad value into InsertTableB.  
If the ID is already in Table A, why do you need to UPPER and REPLACE?  Didn't you do that when you saved ID in Table A?

Comment: @RMANExpress The 2 datasets are saved in one transaction.
The assignment of the id in the responsibleobjectid column happens in our .Net layer, so the assignment is GUID based.
Since they are saved separately (but in the same transaction) we have to do the upper and replace on both saves.

Comment: @RMANExpress I understand that it would be more correct to use a byte[], but what we are doing doesnt seem that wrong, at least not to justify this error. So I'm just trying to understand what could have caused this behavior.

Comment: "The ResponsibleObjectId column is filled with the ID of table A ..." not really.  It comes from a different dataset.  How does the GUID value get into the two datasets?  Is this still happening?  How often - once a day, week, month?

Comment: @RMANExpress it is just an assignment like this: `datasetB.responsibleobjectId = datasetA.Id` It happens many thousands of times a day. Its a medical application, so we are dezling with a lot of data. But still the corruption has happened only a few times.

Comment: Are you using multiple .Net servers?  Is it possible that Table A is saved from one server and Table B from another?  Could there be a difference between servers (NLS settings, ODP version, character set, CHAR/NCHAR, Oracle Client, ... ).  Have you checked MS or Oracle for a possible bug?  Do you have the latest server/client/ODP versions and patches?  Based on the infrequency of this case, it sounds like a bug in some aspect of the stack or it is data dependent.

Comment: The problem with the way you have it is it would seem that you are not capturing where the error is coming from, whether this is in the .NET DAL before being sent to Oracle (my guess) OR some way through the execution of the procedure. I would setup a logging condition now considering @Brian's observation above. That is unlikely to occur naturally, so capture some logging data before you get finished with your transaction. Also, see if you can add that same level of logging to the DAL for the same condition for the value before/after assignment/procedure execution.

Comment: @REW Yes, the logging is probably the way to go to better locate the problem. I'll see what I can do!

Comment: If you are willing to add logging code, why not just fix the code and use the correct data types?  Years ago a senior programmer said to me in a similar situation.... if someone was hitting you on the head with a hammer, would you want them to slow down or stop? Fix it, test it, push it into production and move on.

Comment: @RMANExpress Can you guarantee me that this will fix our problem? Also the cost of adding logging is marginal compared to altering the type.

Comment: Yes, it will fix the problem.

Comment: Curious why there cannot be a foreign key `B.ResponsibleObjectId references A.Id`, it can be null when not available and will likely help you spot the error since setting it to a bad value might fails (unless there is another row with that id, which is unlikely)

Comment: @MiserableVariable Indeed this would help us a lot, but the responsibleObjectId can also be filled with the id of a second table (tableC), so thats why we cannot create a foreign key.

Comment: Hmmm. I would put a before trigger to do integrity check and throw exception to get similar effect to a constraint

Comment: @MiserableVariable Thats a great idea! It would at least guarantee our database integrity...

Answer (score 3):

byte[] idGuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray();

dataSetA.Id = idGuid;

dataSetB.ResponsibleObjectId = idGuid;

/* don't do dataSetB.ResponsibleObjectId = dataSetA.Id

don't do any data type conversions - keep it binary/raw */

Comment: We cannot do `dataSetB.ResponsibleObjectId = idGuid;` because dataSetA is created on the client, passed to the server, and then dataSetB is created (on the server). So we have to do `dataSetB.ResponsibleObjectId = dataSetA.Id`. If you have any evidence that this would fix our problem, then I'd realy be happy to accept your answer. I just don't want to force this big a refactoring on our team to not have the problem fixed. It would be like someone hitting us on the head with a hammer, we turning around because that 'fixes' our problem and then still get hit on the head with the same hammer ;)

Comment: "because dataSetA is created on the client, passed to the server" 
Can you track the clients that created these mismatched Guids?  I have seen issues where clients use a different character set (ex: single vs. multibyte, etc.) cause string "translation" problems.  If you can pass the dataset from client to server, why can't you pass the GUID and then associate it to DatasetB?  Part of the reason to use binary GUIDs is that the values are not translated due to language/character sets differences. Have you checked your software stack to be sure that you are using the latest certified versions?

Comment: Since dataSetA is also saved in tableA and it contains the correct Guid in the database, I don't think the problem originates on the client.

Answer (score 0):

We have some very strong indications that these problems occured because their database setup was not according to our requirements. The oracel db is not running on a dedicated machine and did not have sufficient memory.

The incidents could in alot of cases be matched to problems on their RACs.

We'll try to convice the customer now to upscale their db server.